Tubular neighborhood theorem and extension
Assume $\Sigma^n$ is an embedded submanifold with boundary in $M^n$. Assume $f:\Sigma \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$  is a smooth embedding.
Can we extend $f$ to a smooth embedding on a neighborhood of $U$?
(Remark)Let $U$ be a tubular neighborhood of $\Sigma^n$ in $M^n$. Then there exists a local diffeomorphism $r:U\rightarrow M$ such that $r|_{M}=id$

Do you really assume that $\Sigma$, $M$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$ have the same dimension? In that case (and more generally, if the normal bundle of $\Sigma$ is trivial, you are in  this situation

@Jonas Hi! why does my assumptions imply normal bundle are trivial?
